# How many ways can $n$ students read $r$ out of $n$ papers in such a way that every paper is read $r$ times?

Tags: combinatorics

Already at $n=4, r=2$ this question becomes fairly non-trivial. Can anyone find a generalized formula?

One way to view the question is to ask how many $n,n-$bipartite graphs there exist where every vertex has degree $r$, and where every pair of vertices can have at most one edge. In this approach we cannot only consider isomorphism classes though, we need to label each node and consider every distinct graph.

Comment: For $r=2$, let vertices be $(reader, paper)$ with an edge between them if the reader or the paper is the same.  Then you have a set of loops.  You should be able to set up a recursion to count them.

Comment: What counts as a distinct ‘way’?

Comment: It has the natural meaning from the original question, i.e. two "ways" are different iff at least one student reads different papers in both "ways".

Comment: https://oeis.org/A008300 gives numbers and some references